# Is it possible to implement a ripple-carry adder using the generate construct in VHDL?

Tags: math, vhdl

I'm new to this language and I was trying to implement a 4-bit ripple-carry adder. The code I've written is something like this:

```
fulladder1: fulladder PORT MAP (Input_1_4b(0), Input_2_4b(0), Carry_in, Output_4_b(0), C0);
fulladder2: fulladder PORT MAP (Input_1_4b(1), Input_2_4b(1), C0, Output_4_b(1), C1);
fulladder3: fulladder PORT MAP (Input_1_4b(2), Input_2_4b(2), C1, Output_4_b(2), C2);
fulladder4: fulladder PORT MAP (Input_1_4b(3), Input_2_4b(3), C2, Output_4_b(3), Carry_out);
```

I was wondering if it's possible to write the same circuit using the `GENERATE` construct. Especially in the case one has to deal with a wider parallelism.

In other words: how could I set the first carry_in to 0 and all the others to the previous carry_out (if it's possible)?

I searched for information on internet but I haven't found anything useful.

Comment: [Yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKii2.jpg) it is possible. There are examples on Stack Overflow you can find using search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [4 bit adder in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794131/4-bit-adder-in-vhdl)

Comment: One thing to understand is that any hand coding of adder structure is generally a student exercise.   I would not necessarily expect it to map to an FPGA in any good way.   Instead, I would recommend coding your adder as:  `Y <= A + B;"    Then the synthesis tool figures out the best way to implement the results, which in FPGA is almost always ripple.

Comment: Ok, so you would suggest me not bothering to find any better/more compact solution, because it’s “useless”?